# SerialPort.GetPortNames() creates System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#

I've made a Bootloader implementation in a SAMD21J18A mcu, based on a
Atmel example. I can connect to the bootloader via USB CDC and it is recognized in windows as a COM port with the name: `AT91 USB to Serial Converter`, not showing any problems.

The COM-port works fine, I've made a working Windows Form C# program to download code to the bootloader. In the working program I've just manually set the `PortName`.

Now, I want to make the program more user friendly and want to make a `ComboBox`to enable the user to pick the COM-port to use. Therefore I'm calling the `GetPortNames` function:

```
string[] Ports = null;
Ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

This works fine, as long as I don't plugin my bootloader.
If I attach eg. a FTDI device, it detects the device and adds it to the list, but if I attach the `Bootloader("AT91 USB to Serial Converter")`, then I get a `System.StackOverflowException` on the `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` function.

Does anyone know what is wrong with `GetPortNames` or the USB CDC driver?

---

Thanks for your help mjwills :-)

The complete program were too large to show here, so I decided to make a short program showing the problem. However, the new short program didn't have this problem. So, found out the problem didn't directly originate from the line refered to by visual studio.
Anyway, here's the function which created the problem:

```
    // Update comport pull-down list:
    private void UpdateComPortList()
    {
        string[] Ports = null;
        Ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        int index = -1;
        string ComPortName = null;
        comboBoxComPort.Items.Clear();
        do
        {
            index += 1;
            comboBoxComPort.Items.Add(Ports[index]);
            //if(Properties.Settings.Default.comPort == Ports[index]) comboBoxComPort.SelectedIndex = index;
        }
        while (!((Ports[index] == ComPortName) || (index == Ports.GetUpperBound(0))));
        comboBoxComPort.Items.Add("update list...");
    }
```

If I remove the line which I've now commented, the program works.
I think the problem is that, I try to select an item while at the same time adding items...

Comment: What did you discover when you looked at the stack when it overflowed?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: GetPortNames() cannot cause a stackoverflow by itself.  It is merely the first victim of recursive code.  A likely victim since it grovels in the registry, that takes a fair amount of stack space.  Set a breakpoint on the method call, the 2nd time it hits you need to look at the debugger's stack trace to see how it got there again.